# Inconsistent stroke fill pattern with dygraphs stepPlot fillGraph

Tags: javascript, charts, nan, dygraphs

When rendering a [stepPlot](http://dygraphs.com/options.html#stepPlot) based dygraphs chart from multiple series containing gaps (encoded in the native data format as `NaN` per [documentation](http://dygraphs.com/options.html#connectSeparatedPoints) and [test examples](http://dygraphs.com/tests/independent-series.html)), I get occasional portions of the chart containing inconsistent dots/stroke patterns. Here is [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/multidis/0xm8f383/4/): scroll to the last chart. Please note that stroke itself is disabled (`strokeWidth: 0`), only fill should be present (intended behavior).

These inconsistencies appear even more visible with a denser chart:
[image: Dygraphs inconsistent stroke fill pattern]

Note that they appear not only at the boundary of different color steps but also at NaN/value step boundaries.

Is there some problematic combination of options that I am asking the chart to apply? Is it a dygraphs bug? Should data encoding be different? Thanks.

Comment: Which version of dygraphs are you using? You might try using a version built from github master—there have been many changes since the last release.

Comment: Using `dygraph-combined` v1.1.1; tried the version built from github master (latest commit 2015-11-16) and the same issue persists (along with some other breaking changes when using [angular-dygraphs](https://github.com/cdjackson/angular-dygraphs)).